# jQuery only allow latin characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want has a js code for allow type only latin charter with number and Special Characters(Alt Keyboard Sequences, EX:`!@#$%^&*()_|}{~!"?>:<?/][\=-`'`, ...), i tried like this, but it does not work for latin number and the invisible character Keyboard.what do i do?

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/oosjtmgg/

```js
        $(".latin_letters").on("keypress", function(event) {
            var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = /[A-Za-z ]/g;
            var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        $('.latin_letters').on("paste", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" class="latin_letters">
```

Comment: What is "invisible character Keyboard"?

Comment: @guest271314 EX this: !@#$%^&*()_|}{~!, ...

Comment: Are "!@#$%^&*()_|}{~!," characters valid input? What does "..." represent as to valid or invalid input characters?

Comment: only stop typing.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

only add:-     var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = "/^[-@./#&+\w\s]*$/";

```js
$(".latin_letters").on("keypress", function(event) {
        var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = /^[-@./#&+\w\s]*$/;
            var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        $('.latin_letters').on("paste", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" class="latin_letters" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".latin_letters").on("keydown", function(event) {
            var allowed = /[A-Za-z0-9!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_|}{~">:<\?/\]\[\\=\- ]/g;
            var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || allowed.test(key)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
$('.latin_letters').on("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" class="latin_letters">
```

This will work for you. You had not tested numbers and signals before.